# Storing timezone information for a timestamp in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, cql

I understand that Cassandra stores timestamps as seconds (or microseconds) since epoch.  So if I care about the time zone where the particular event took place do I need to store it in a separate column?  Is there any best practice or suggestions for how to store that?  Integer offset from GMT?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We store millions of timestamps and their timezones in our Cassandra cluster per day.

Our recommended practice is to store timestamps as two values:

1. Store the timestamp itself as a timestamp type or bigint and always align it to UTC (we use .NET datetimes, which start from year zero and not the UNIX epoch, so we have to use bigint.)
2. Store the UTC offset as a bigint, in microseconds

That way all of our timestamps are, by default, using the same timezone across the board. However, whenever we need to do something in local time we can just fetch the UTC offset column and subtract it from the timestamp in order to get local time.

Comment: Do you ever need to operate on a timestamp in an arbitrary timezone (i.e. a timezone not in the offset you have saved)? Does this approach help with that?

Comment: @CrescentFresh yes - if you know that the datetime is always stored in UTC and you need to operate in some other timezone, you can always calculate the datetime in that third timezone (not UTC, not the stored timezone) by just applying the UTC offset to the stored datetime.

Comment: isn't storing UTC offset wrong? Why not storing the time zone info so you can compute the UTC offset. This way if a UTC offset changes your values will adjust.

Comment: @JonathanNappee yes, that's a better idea